# MSTest: Get output message from Assert?

Tags: c#, logging, console, mstest

I'm writing integration tests using the MSTest framework.  The tests and code under test all have significant logging built into them.

I'm trying to figure out a way to hook into the Assert's output so I can write it to the log files along with the rest of log.

For example, if I have a test method like

```
[TestMethod]
SomeRandomIntegrationTest()
{
  //Code to actually run the test, and includes logging.

  Assert.AreEqual(true, false, "This error message should also appear in the log");
}
```

I would get

> Message: Assert.AreEqual failed.  Expected true.  Got false.  This error message should also appear in the log.

in my log file.

I tried doing

```
private StringBuilder testOutputBuilder;
private StringWriter testOutputWriter;
private TextWriter originalWriter;

[TestInitialize]
public virtual void Initialize()
{
  //Redirect the test output into the log files
  testOutputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  testOutputWriter = new StringWriter(testOutputBuilder);
  originalWriter = Console.Out;
  Console.SetOut(testOutputWriter);
}

[TestCleanup]
public virtual void TestCleanup()
{
  if (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome != UnitTestOutcome.Passed)
  {
     //File logging happens here using the testOutputBuilder
  }
  Console.SetOut(originalWriter);
  testOutputWriter.Dispose();
}
```

but the `testOutputBuilder` returns an empty string.

How can I grab the string outputs from the assert methods in MSTest?

Comment: The Assertion throws a exception, these are displayed through the `Console.Error`. I don't use mtest myself. But I think that if you loop `Console.Error` into your steam you should see the assert messages pop up there.

Comment: @NickOtten Tried using `Console.SetError(testOutputWriter)`.  No dice.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a workaround using separate function:

```
public string WriteErrorToFile(TextWriter textwriter, string errorMessage)
{
        textwriter.WriteLine(errorMessage);
        return errorMessage;
}
```

and code inside test should be modified like:

```
Assert.AreEqual(true, false, WriteErrorToFile(originalWriter, "This error message should also appear in the log"));
```

If you have only one log file then you can remove first parameter to the function.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I did this:

```
public void OutputAssert(Action func)
    {
        try
        {
            func();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OutputToFile(ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }            
    }
```

And then in the test:

```
[TestMethod]        
public void TestAssertOutput()
    {
        OutputAssert(() => Assert.AreEqual(false, true, "test message"));
    }
```

The output being:

> ```
> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<False>. Actual:<True>. test message
> ```